# Can't run a .py file AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'

Tags: python, flask, collections, traceback

I have a ubuntu server and am trying to run a website using python w/ flask Running Python 3.11.4
I run the command:

```
python app.py
```

Expected behavior: It should execute the without error.

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/valorant-hours-played/app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from flask_navigation import Navigation
  File "/root/valorant-hours-played/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_navigation/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .api import Navigation
  File "/root/valorant-hours-played/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_navigation/api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .navbar import NavigationBar
  File "/root/valorant-hours-played/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_navigation/navbar.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .item import ItemCollection
  File "/root/valorant-hours-played/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_navigation/item.py", line 131, in <module>
    class ItemCollection(collections.MutableSequence,
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableSequence'
```

I belive collections.MutableMapping is outdated and should be collections.abc.MutableMapping the only problem is I have no idea what this means and how to fix this.

I tried updating .../site-packages/flask_navigation/item.py so that
`import collections` --> `import collections.abc` that didnt solve the issue so I am unsure how to go from here?

Is it as simple as just changing all instances of `import collections` to `import collections.abc` in all the files under flask_navigation or do I need to do something else? Such as Upgrading related package? OR `from collections.abc import MutableSequence`

Sorry if its similar to other threads but I'm just a bit new it's my first time setting up a flask app in python and I can't get it to work having read all the other threads.

BTW it run fine on python 3.9.1 so shall I just downgrade to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would `import collections.abc` then `ItemCollection(collections.abc.MutableSequence)` if you control the source.

Comment: The error happens inside the `flask_navigation` module, so I would try updating that.

Comment: `flask_navigation` is in public archive since `2017-11-19`. Seems, that a new fork required.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up getting rid of the flask_navigation module completely

For Python 3.10 navbar I [utilized a context processor that is capable of injecting variables into each route](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/flask-nav-navigation-alternative-for-python-3-10)